# Problems with python-bitcoinrpc and python-monerorpc

Tags: python, rpc, bitcoin, json-rpc, monero

I am having problems connecting to both bitcoin and monero's RPC servers.
I am using python-bitcoinrpc and python-monerorpc as libraries and somehow they cannot connect at the same time.
Here is the code i am using:

```
from monerorpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException
arg = { 
    "destinations": 
    [{
        "amount": 499978865000, 
        "address": "A2Xt28bHwF7TaqERoUV4QMTKkpytNMLVRaKGHnasdeNz6WEEWZ6K9LHZFXgNbQhskC24ejuMxfWzpNBG56EecXhdFqPG3GK",
    }],
    "account_index": 0,
    "priority": 0,
    "get_tx_key": True,
    }

btc = AuthServiceProxy(service_url="http://<username>:<password>@server-ip:port", timeout=120)
xmr = AuthServiceProxy(service_url='http://<username>:<password>@server-ip:port/json_rpc') 
print(xmr.getnewaddress("", "p2sh-segwit"))
print(xmr.getbalance())
```

I get this error when i connect:

```
-342: non-JSON HTTP response with '401 Unauthorized' from server
```

Any help will be well appreciated!

Comment: Hi there! Which line is triggering the error? And what things have you tried to fix it so far?

Comment: It is line 17 `print(xmr.getbalance()) ` ,  apparently i have to run them in a separate file, which isn't great and i want to run them in the same file but i really do not understand how and why the error is caused

Comment: Does print function on line 16 print an address? Also it looks strange that you use the same ip-address and port number for both bitcoin and monero.

Comment: Indeed, the print function on line 16 does print an address. And i am not using the same port and host for both, and that's what made me confused! I think there's a problem with the `AuthServiceProxy` since it is included in both and modified in monerorpc

Answer (score 0):

You're importing `AuthServiceProxy` from both libs, and expecting Python to remember which lib each one comes from. I would try two things:

1. Import both `AuthServiceProxy` classes using an alias (and rename each call respectively)
2. Ensure that you can call the monero and bitcoin endpoints *independently* of each other without errors.

I'm suspecting that both calls made to `AuthServiceProxy` are actually both bitcoinrpc lib calls which might explain the error (in that you may actually be calling the same endpoint in too-quick-succession and resulting in the API complaining).

Comment: Already tried that and didn't work, and that's what i am suspecting as well but kind confusing!

Comment: Humour me and run the slightly modified code I have entered in this paste: https://pastebin.com/LahfTVS8 (Note the comments too).

Comment: I solved it, just have to do some changes in the AuthServiceProxy

Comment: Well let us know what the fix is in order to help others who discover this in the future. If my answer helped at all, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Hi @EscrowMyCoins I am facing the same issue. Could you please post your fix.